# Autoplaying videos on mobile

Tags: video, youtube, slider, autoplay

I wonder what the current situation is re videos autoplaying on mobile devices. I know that the mobile networks have limited this as well as ios, android and ipad, and I have looked online and in here for various workarounds. Opinions where it's not worth editing the code because things change rapidly when it comes to permissions and using certain elements. The video is for use in the header. I wonder if there is a comprehensive tool to test video across mobile devices.

As things stand, videos can only autoplay on certain devices as long as mute is included. Ultimately I'd like to be able to have a video autoplay as soon as the site loads and for the video file to be compressed to minimise load time on a web page. I understand Facebook got around this by creating their own canvas on which to load videos thus enabling autoplaying on mobile devices.  How true is it that functions and parameters such as autoplay, playVideo(), loadVideoById() won't work in all mobile environments?

If there is a workaround that will work and won't affect the load time of a page I would be grateful for any ideas. I understand that a GIF is a workaround so users can identify that there is something there to click on and watch; but a GIF can take up to 5 times more bandwidth on mobile than a video so I wonder about the implications of that too.

Rev Slider is being used to display the video in html5 and the video is embedded on the page, as opposed to just the video url being used. Some API functions / methods:
    https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/api/

Could the Rev Slider API be altered in some way? Is there a functions php command I could add that is guaranteed to give autoplay results across all mobile devices?

Could it be an issue with the cache / or a plugin on a site which affects the ability to autoplay on mobile?

You Tube gives these examples of proper use (but autoplay doesn't apply to all mobile devices unless there is a workaround?):
* Use API with existing 
* Loud Playback
* Thirdly an example which sets player parameters to automatically play the video when it loads and to hide the video player's controls. It also adds event listeners for all of the events that the API broadcasts.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': onPlayerError
    }
  });
}
```

---

I tested on Browserstack to see how the home page would display across 15 main devices and display was successful accross 11 of the 15 devices:

Successful...
Windows 8.1ie 11Windows 8.1firefox 30Windows 8ie 10Windows 7ie 9Windows XPfirefox 3.6 OS X Yosemiteopera 12.15OS X Maverickschrome 36iPhone 5S(portrait)

unsuccessful...
Windows 7ie 8   OS X Yosemitesafari 8iPhone 6 Plus(portrait)iPad 4th(portrait)

For info purposes, Browserstack considers these to be the main mobile types:

Apple iPhone SE 
Apple iPhone 6s 
Google Nexus 6 
Samsung Galaxy S5 
Apple iPad Air 2 Tablet
Google Nexus 7 Tablet
Nokia Lumia 520 
Google Nexus 4 
Apple iPhone 6 Plus 
Samsung Galaxy Note 3 
Google Nexus 5X 
Samsung Galaxy S7 
Amazon Kindle Fire HDX 8.9 Tablet
Apple iPad Mini 2 Tablet
Sony Xperia Z 
Apple iPhone 4s 
Samsung Galaxy S4
Motorola G (2nd Gen) 
HTC One X 
Blackberry Z10
Samsung Galaxy Note 4 
Google Nexus 9 Tablet
Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 Tablet

### Windows Surface RT 2 Tablet

I used Responsinator.com and found that the video autoplayed played across these devices:
iPhone 5 portrait · width: 320px
iPhone 5 landscape · width: 568px
iPhone 6 portrait · width: 375px
iPhone 6 landscape · width: 667px
iPhone 6 Plump portrait · width: 414px
iPhone 6 Plump landscape · width: 736px
Android (Nexus 4) portrait · width: 384px
Android (Nexus 4) landscape · width: 600px
iPad portrait · width: 768px
iPad landscape · width: 1024px

Some thoughts and ideas would be really welcome.

Best Regards

Comment: A quick note: it is typically (but not always) more dependent on the OS version than the device for iOS - from 10 onwards the <video playsinline> tag is supported and if you google that you should see some examples. I would check what version of the OS is running on the devices for your tests also. For example i would have expected the iPhone 5s and iPhone 6 to give the same results if the browser and OS version were the same.